# Python Class Inheritance Function and Pass Parameters From Child

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
class BaseMenu(object):
    def display(self):
        header = "FooBar YO"
        term = getTerminalSize()
        #sys.stdout.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")
        print header.center(term, '*')
        #print sub_menu.center(term, '+')
        print "Please choose which option:"
        for i in options:
            print(
                str(options.index(i)+1) + ") "
            )

class Servers(BaseMenu):
    def __init__(self):
        #super(Servers, self).__init__("server")
        pass

    def list_foo(self):
        pass
    def list_bar(self):
        pass
    options = (
        list_foo,
        list_bar
        )
```

Trying to make a series of text menus starting with Main Menu -> Servers sub menu. When Servers() inherits display() from BaseClass, how can I make the inherited function display() receive options tuple and sub_menu = "Server Menu" string that are contained in Servers() class?

Comment: ncurses helps a lot with this sort of thing, does it not?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `self.options` and `self.sub_menu` in the `display` function, but why are you referencing them at all in the `BaseMenu` class which knows nothing about `options` or `sub_menu`?

A second issue, you're passing the `"server"` argument to a class whose `__init__` takes no arguments so you'll need to add that.

If you are intending to never instantiate a `BaseMenu` object, then it is an *Abstract Base Class* (or *ABC*).  You can define it as such using pythons `abc` module to make sure the inheriting class defines the properties you are expecting:

```
import abc

class BaseMenu(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta  #indicate that this is an ABC

    @abc.abstractproperty  # prevent derived classes that don't have options
    def options(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def sub_menu(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self, menu_name): # takes the menu name as an argument ("server")
        self.menu_name = menu_name

    def display(self):
        header = "FooBar YO"
        term = getTerminalSize()
        print header.center(term, '*')
        print self.sub_menu.center(term, '+') # NOTE self.sub_menu
        print "Please choose which option:"
        for i in self.options: # NOTE self.options
            print(self.options.index(i)+1 + ") ")
```

If any class tries to inherit from BaseMenu without defining `options` and `sub_menu` it will result in a `TypeError` like the following upon instantiation:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Servers with abstract methods options
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I get completly what you are asking here, so tell me, what about this ?

```
class BaseMenu(object):

    # Added some attributes here:
    menuName = ""
    options = ()

    def __init__(self, menu_name, opt):
        self.menuName = menu_name  # = "Servers Menu" when instantiated as Server
        self.options = opt         # the passed when instantiated as Server

    def display(self):

        # Use self.menuName and self.options here

        #...
        for i in self.options:
            print(
                str(self.options.index(i)+1) + ") " + str(i)
            )

class Servers(BaseMenu):

    def list_foo(self):
        pass
    def list_bar(self):
        pass

    options = (
        list_foo,
        list_bar
        )

    def __init__(self, menu_name):
        super(Servers, self).__init__(menu_name, self.options)
```

Instantiate  `Servers` class like this:

```
servers = Servers("Servers Menu")
servers.display()
```

Outputs:

```
1) <function list_foo at 0x29e06e0>
2) <function list_bar at 0x29e0758>
```

Would it fit ?